# Django, how to set value in forms.ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a question for you. I have the following Model:

```
class Centro_di_costo(models.Model):
    centro_di_costo = models.CharField('Centro di costo', max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return   self.centro_di_costo

class AltriCosti(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES= [
        ('VARIABILE', 'VARIABILE'),
        ('FISSO', 'FISSO'),
    ]
    centro_di_costo = models.ForeignKey(Centro_di_costo) 
    sub_centro_di_costo = models.CharField('Categoria', max_length=30)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    price=models.DecimalField()
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
```

I use it in a lot of view, but in one of them I wanna set the value without passing from the POST request. 
So I have tried to set the ModelForm in the following manner:

```
class ModCollaboratori(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AltriCosti
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModCollaboratori, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.fields['centro_di_costo'].value= "Servizi di Produzione"
        self.fields['sub_centro_di_costo'].value = "Collaboratori esterni"
        self.fields['status'].value = "VARIABILE"
```

But It does not work. How could I fix the code to work?

Comment: If you do not use `request.POST`, you can simply construct a model object.

Comment: In which manner? The models have other field that I have not get in the answer. I have in total 5 fields, three of them (centro_di_costo, sub_centro_di_costo and status) I want to put a value without passing from the request

Comment: then you exclude these from your model fields, and "inject" these by the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude fields from your form:

```
class ModCollaboratori(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AltriCosti
        exclude = ['centro_di_costo', 'sub_centro_di_costo', 'status']
```

Then in your view you can "inject" value for these fields:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModCollaboratori(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.sub_centro_di_costo = 'Collaboratori esterni'
            form.instance.status = 'VARIABILE'
            form.instance.centro_di_costo = Centro_di_costo.objects.get_or_create(
                centro_di_costo='Servizi di Produzione'
            )[0]
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = ModCollaboratori()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I understood your solution but I have in my model other two variables that are get through the `ModCollaboratori` form.

Comment: Okey but I don't understand where I have to add the initial parameters. In my form?

Comment: @Jfix91: you don't you exclude these (such that the user does not override these), and then you specify these in the view, see edit.

Comment: Thanks works, the only problem is about `form.instance.centro_di_costo_id = … (primary key)`.  Django give me `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`.

Comment: @Jfix91: well you need to specify the primary key of the object you link to. That can *not* be string, since a `ForeignKey` saves the primary key of the object.

Comment: Okey I have just added in the answer the ForeignKey `Centro_di_costo(models.Model)`. The model have the following queryset: id=2, Centro_di_costo="Servizi di Produzione".How could modify my code to achive my aim?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213930/discussion-between-jfix91-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

for your code

```
self.fields['status'].value = "VARIABLE"
```

to make it work change to

```
self.instance.status = "VARIABLE"
```

Result:

Status: **VARIABLE**

Answer (score 0):

basically `ModelForm.__init__()` will populate instance values into form.
but if we add extra field to this form, we will need to populate it by ourself in kwargs["initial"],
because this field not include in the model.

```py
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    custom_field = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["initial"]["custom_field"] = "xxxxx"
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```